# maven-resources-plugin breaks the resource copy to test-classes

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

Normally, my POM file is working fine and all unit tests pass and all artifacts are packaged properly.  However, once I've added this maven-resources-plugin to create specific configuration depending upon profile all my tests fail because nothing in 'src/test/resources' is copied to 'test-classes':

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${config.dir}/${project.activeProfiles[1].id}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I don't understand why this would block the copying of test resources.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to add some configuration:

```
<testResources>
    <testResource><directory>src/test/resources</directory></testResource>
</testResources>
```

Comment: Good point, but I already confirmed that 'src/test/resources' is copied properly by convention when I simply remove the maven-resources-plugin block above.

Comment: Yes, true enough. I believe when you include the maven-resources-plugin, however you will be obligated to explicitly include this configuration to achieve the effect you expect and desire. I do it myself and I vaguely recall fighting the battle with Maven.

Answer (score 2):

After much trial and error, I came to a solution.  The maven-resources-plugin needed to be attached to the process-resources phase in order for everything to resolve as expected.  Now, this may not be the best answer, but it worked for me.  Let me know if you have a better solution.

```
<executions>
  <execution>
     <id>create specific server configuration</id> 
     <phase>process-resources</phase> 
     <goals>
       <goal>resources</goal> 
     </goals>
    <configuration>
    /** as above **/
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: If this is the answer then you should accept it (you can even if you are the author of the question).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to get your test resources as main resources, not test resources.

I've done it with this code:

```
<testResources>
 <testResource>
  <directory>src/test/java</directory>
   <filtering>true</filtering>
   <includes><include>**/*.xml</include></includes>
  </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Comment: It gives me that testResources is not allowed her